# How to show white background, on html page loader, instead of page content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, loader

I want show white background on loader page.
I tried to use background: #ffffff, and background-color: #ffffff but it does not work, and it shows still page content.

Here are my codes:

```js
window.onload =
function(){
    document.getElementById("loading")
    .style.display ="none"
}
```

```css
.loader{
    border: 1px  solid #ffffff;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    border-left: 1px solid #db3535;
    border-right: 1px solid #db3535;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    z-index: 999;
}
.loader-a{
    border: 1px  solid #ffffff;
    border-top: 1px solid #db3535;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #db3535;
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    margin-top: -60px;
    z-index: 999;

}
.will{
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 999;

    
}
@keyframes spin{
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100%{transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div id="loading">
  <div class="loader"></div>
  <div class="loader-a"></div>
  <div class="will">
    <h1">Loading...</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

any solution?

everything works fine about the loader. but I don't want it show the page content while it is loading page content.

Comment: Aside from the typo in your HTML's `<h1>` element... Can you clarify what specifically isn't working as expected in the code snippet above?

Comment: the loader works fine ok, but it shows raw content of the page during the loading, I want to show a full white screen that the loader is the middle of the page just before contents load.

Comment: Have you tried assigning a background color to the div? By default, all divs are transparent to show the bodys background color for example. `#loading { background: white }`

Comment: @MahdiAzimi: The snippet above shows "a full white screen" for me.  Though when I first run it there is a *very brief* display of some content, which is hidden faster than I can see what it is.  Perhaps that's a milisecond delay in executing the JavaScript code shown?  Is that what you mean?  If so, why use JavaScript for that style rule instead of CSS?  It's not really clear to me what you're trying to ask.

Comment: yes but it shows contents also.

Comment: @David I mean, loader should be with a background, and I want this background be white, So, I tried `background: white, background-color: #fff` in #loading, but when I refresh the website, behind the loader is all page contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new code with blue background for you. add this CSS top of your css code

```
#loading {
    position: absolute;
    background: #1117cf;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

add a 1 second interval to your code to see loading:

```
window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById("loading")
            .style.display = "none"
    }, 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the div (`#loading`) absolute position and set `0` to all sides such as top, right, bottom, left.

Add this line of code to your existing one.

```
#loading {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

I hope it will work